# How to install CUDA on ATI card, Ubuntu

Tags: c++, cuda

I need to compile FLANN, a C++ library. Compilation requires
CUDA.

How do install CUDA on Ubuntu, given that I have ATI graphics card?

I need to install it so that the FLANN compilation finishes,
I am not going to use any CUDA related code.

Thank you

Comment: you can't, CUDA is a proprietary technology and Nvidia only provides it on selected GPU/drivers pairs.

Comment: In Windows you can try using a CUDA Emulator such as http://www.techpowerup.com/119073/NVIDIA_CUDA_Emulator_for_every_PC.html

Answer (score 4):

If you need the CUDA only for compilation, and no run, it is OK to download latest CUDA Toolkit for ubuntu from NVIDIA website and install it on your ATI-based system. Installation is easy and you only need to run the .run file. Install it in the default path and after installation add the following lines  to the end of `~/.bashrc` to have the `nvcc` on command line (for compilation of FLANN):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib
```